# Getting the Parent Function that Created an Instance

Tags: javascript

So this is a somewhat weird problem that may not be possible but I was wondering if it is possible to get a variable linkage of the function that created an instance from javascript.

for example, i'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
function MyObject(){
    console.log(this) // traces out the instance
    console.log(MyObject) // traces out the function
    console.log(this.parentClass) //Would like this to trace out the function as well. (or a similar call like it)
}

var test = new MyObject();
```

Is this at all possible? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible **if** the `prototype` objects on the functions haven't been replaced, or if the code replacing them keeps the linkage as it is by default.

The `constructor` property is (by default and *convention*) the property you're looking for:

```
var test = new MyObject();
console.log(test.constructor === MyObject); // "true"
```

Note all of the caveats above, though. For instance, this is perfectly valid (and not particularly atypical) code:

```
function MyObject() {
}
MyObject.prototype = {
    foo: function() { /* ... */ },
    bar: function() { /* ... */ }
};
```

This is a common pattern, although one I don't recommend. Instead of *adding to* the object referred to by the `MyObject.prototype` property (an object that was set up by the JavaScript engine when creating `MyObject`), that code is creating an entirely *new* object and assigning it to the `prototype` property, making it refer to the new object. If that has been done, then the `constructor` property has been broken, and you can't use it the way you want to use it.

The `constructor` property on the default `prototype` object on functions is a funny thing about JavaScript. It's defined quite clearly in the specification that it will be there (it's [§13.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2) if anyone wants to read up), but as far as I'm aware nothing in the JavaScript engine actually uses it. (It isn't, for instance, used for `instanceof`.)